# how to create a stacked area chart in lattice?

Tags: r, plot, lattice, stacked-area-chart

Consider this simple `tibble`

```
tibble(time = c(ymd('2019-01-01'),
                ymd('2019-01-02'),
                ymd('2019-01-03'),
                ymd('2019-01-04'),
                ymd('2019-01-05')),
       var1 = c(1,2,3,4,5),
       var2 = c(2,0,1,2,0))
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  time        var1  var2
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 2019-01-01     1     2
2 2019-01-02     2     0
3 2019-01-03     3     1
4 2019-01-04     4     2
5 2019-01-04     5     0
```

I would like to create a stacked area chart using `lattice`, where `time` is on the `x` axis and `var1` and `var2` are stacked (on the `y` axis) over time.

Is it possible to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: no, not cumulative. at time t you plot (var1) and (var1+var2). really something like https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/136-stacked-area-chart/

Comment: Follow up questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56582808/multiarea-chart-in-lattice and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56579576/how-to-change-the-fill-color-in-a-lattice-plot for future reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tibble)
library(lubridate)
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
library(reshape2)


df1 <- tibble(time = c(ymd('2019-01-01'),
                       ymd('2019-01-02'),
                       ymd('2019-01-03'),
                       ymd('2019-01-04'),
                       ymd('2019-01-05')),
              var1 = c(1,2,3,4,5),
              var2 = c(2,0,1,2,0))

df2 <- df1
df2$var2 <- df2$var2 + df2$var1
df2 <- melt(df2, id.vars = "time")


xyplot(value~time, df2, group=variable,
       panel=function(x,y,...){
             panel.xyarea(x,y,...)
             panel.xyplot(x,y,...)},
      col=c("red","blue"),
      alpha=c(0.8,0.4))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ ;) I know you can add two `lattice` plots together as well (simply like `p1+p2`) using `latticeExtra` but I couldn't get that to work here.

Comment: its ok. do you know if a secondary axis can be added here?

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ just left my desk, on my cell now. Not off the top of my head, but I'm pretty sure it's possible.

Comment: funnily enough, the `col` arguments applies to the dots, not to the area. do you think we can control the area color as well?

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ use fill maybe

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ use it as a panel argument.

Comment: I tried. didnt work I get `> panel.xyarea(x,y,...,col  =c("red","blue"))
Error: '...' used in an incorrect context`

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ I used fill inside the layout and did not get an error but still no actual change of color. This can be another question as a follow up.